# Boas práticas com contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html

Acabo de descobrir a tag `contenteditable` e estou a usa-la em meus projetos.

Quais as boas práticas que eu devo ter em relação a segurança, já que essa tag possibilita `colar` qualquer coisa em sua forma original, bugando o site em certos casos.

Uso JavaScript, e gostaria de me prevenir contra principalmente a desfiguração da página.

Comment: Uma boa prática é não usa-lá, na minha opinião é claro. Já descobriu algum caso que seja melhor usar ela do que usar um `textarea` ou `input` que já servem para terem o conteúdo editado ? Pense no outro lado também, acha que um usuário comum vai saber que o `contenteditable` ele pode clicar para editar - e editar o que ? - sendo que pra ele sempre vai parecer que é um texto fixo ? Eu acho que o usuário final malemar consegue usar um campo de texto da forma que eu espero, imagina o problema que não seria com um campo desse tipo ?

Comment: @WilliamNovak Concordo que não é uma boa prática usar o atributo `contenteditable`, porém é por outro motivo: porque não tem evento `onchange` ou algo do tipo. A única maneira de detectar se o texto foi modificado é usando `requestAnimationFrame` ou `setTimeout`.

Comment: se os dados da página vão ser lançados no servidor, então faça uma filtragem de conteúdo, se o que está sendo enviado respeita os padrões impostos, assim não precisará se preocupar com alguém editando o html ou css, ou qualquer outra coisa, pois isso só ficará alterado no pc do mesmo que editar